# Can sentiment "analysis" be called sentiment "recognition"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, pattern-recognition, sentiment-analysis

In sentiment analysis application of NLP, we are basically required to predict an emotion given a piece of text.

Can we say that we are doing "sentiment recognition" instead of "sentiment analysis" ? I am asking this because, sentiment "analysis" should be a more extensive and involved process compared to just predicting an emotion.

Any comments on this.

Answer (score 2):

While you may be right that a different name might be more suitable for *sentiment analysis*, **it is better to stick with it**.

The term **Sentiment analysis** has been actively used since ~2004 and it is a well established term [1]. If you talk to other NLP researchers, *sentiment analysis* makes it clear what you are talking about, even if the actual words don't describe perfectly what it is. On the other hand, *sentiment recognition* is a confusing term half-way between *sentiment analysis* and [***emotion recognition***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_recognition)—a similar but broader problem involving also analysis of facial expression.

See also [What is the difference between emotion recognition and sentiment analysis?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-emotion-recognition-and-sentiment-analysis)

---

[1]: Mäntylä, M.V., Graziotin, D. and Kuutila, M., 2018. The evolution of sentiment analysis—A review of research topics, venues, and top cited papers. Computer Science Review, 27, pp.16-32.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of "analysis" are different from that of "recognition".

Ideally successful result of analysis should give you a spectrum of results. The "rules" of such analysis would be valid across similar classes of datasets.

Whereas a successful result of "recognition" would be to evaluate the given dataset in order to match it to a set of pre-analysed reference point and to find the best match.

Applications of NLP might be doing"Sentiment Recognition" but what we want to achieve is ultimately "Sentiment Analysis"